# java xpath compare formatted date with current date in xml

Tags: java, xml, date, xpath

i have such XML-File:

```
<books>
<book>
    <id>1</id>
    <validFrom>23.11.2012</validFrom>
    <validTo>26.09.2012</validTo>
</book>
<book>
    <id>2</id>
    <validFrom>14.09.2012</validFrom>
    <validTo>01.08.2012</validTo>
</book>
```

I want to remove from this xml file all books, where the date validTo is before current date, but I have problems with query in XPath.

I tried in different ways.

```
XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr 
         = xpath.compile("//book[validTo < fn:current-date()]");

Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        removeFindNodes()
    }
```

How can I format the validTo to be able to compare with current date?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsd:date` expects the format to be `yyyy-MM-dd`, whilst yours is `dd.MM.yyyy`. You could try to use a combination of `substring`, `translate`, and `concat` to transform your format, but by then your XPath expression would become slightly complicated. An alternative solution, and far easier to read, is to fetch all `validTo` nodes and *then* do the comparison with Java:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//book/validTo");
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
now.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
  Node validToNode = nodes.item(i);
  Date validTo = df.parse(validToNode.getTextContent());
  if (validTo.compareTo(now.getTime()) < 0) {
    Node bookNode = validToNode.getParentNode();
    removeNode(bookNode);
  }
}
```